# Choose data to display with D3 by data's value

Tags: javascript, sql, asp.net, d3.js, visualization

I am bringing in data from SQL and storing it in hidden labels, that I then display using D3 as a scatter plot.  I have an x-value label, y-value label, radius label, and then a fourth label which we'll call a set label.

Basically, I have seven sets of data and want to only show one at a time (the user will be able to choose from a dropdown or radio buttons or whatever to pick the one to show, that's easy).  Is there a way in D3 to say only show points whose set data = X?

Here's my relevant setup so far:

```
var x_data = $('.CostImport').text().split(',');
var y_data = $('.PriceImport').text().split(',');
var r_data = $('.SalesImport').text().split(',');
var c_data = $('.ZoneImport').text().split(',');

var data = [];

for (i = 0; i < x_data.length; i++) {
   data.push({ "x": x_data[i], "y": y_data[i], "c": c_data[i], "r": r_data[i] });
}


 vis.selectAll("circle")
            .data(data)
                .enter().append("svg:circle")
                    .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.x) })
                    .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.y) })
                    .attr("stroke-width", "none")
                    .attr("fill", function (d) { return c(d.c) })
                    .attr("fill-opacity", .75)
                    .attr("r", function (d) { return r(d.r) });
```

Currently I'm coloring data by set value but it's too busy and overlapping.  I realize I could just load separate labels and data for each set (eg x1_data, x2_data, ....) but I was hoping to make this more robust in case the number of sets changes.

Comment: As an update, I've modified the last line in an attempt to only pull the third set:
    .attr("r", function (d) { if (d.c = 3) return r(d.r); return 0 });

but am still seeing all sets.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the last line to:

```
.attr("r", function (d) { if (d.c == 3) return r(d.r); else return 0 });
```

works perfectly.  Too much time in SQL made me forgot to double equals.